# Could read() / recv() functions get stuck, even if i am working with select()?

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have been learning about sockets, I have understood that you can attend the clients by threads or using select() function, right?

According what i understand, if you call:

```
select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

The function indicates which of the specified file descriptors is ready for reading, ready for writing, or has an error condition pending, so if i then call:

`read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);` or `recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);`

The function will get stuck until that finds something to read or recive at least on one of the specified file descriptors or until a signal arrives that needs to be delivered, and that signal arrives in *timeout*, right?

Well, could read() / recv() functions gets stuck indefinitely, even if i am working with select() and a specific timeout?

Because I am trying to implement a client that is capable of sending and receiving messages and images, it apparently sends the file correctly, but after having received the image, the program keep waiting in read() for ever.

This is the function that is responsible for receiving the image once *select()* has been called and it has been identified that an image will be received

```
void receive_image(int sock, FILE *fp_write){
    char buffer[256];
    char byte;

    fp_write = fopen("archivoRecibido.bmp","wb");
    enviarConfirmacion(sock);
    enviarMD5SUM(sock);

    while(read(sock, &byte, sizeof(byte)) > 0){
        fwrite(&byte,sizeof(byte),1,fp_write);
    }
    fclose(fp_write);
    puts("***PERFECT***");
}
```

The matter for which I have doubts about my knowledge is that in theory the file should not close and should not receive the image, but this is not the case, the image is received correctly, what happens is that I cannot return to the main cycle to send another message because i think that it get stuck reading.

Comment: You are calling `read` in a loop. `select` only tells you there is something to read and not how much. The loop will consume all the data and then block on the `read`.

Comment: Do you have the socket set to non-blocking?

Comment: You will want to take a look at [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Excellent up to date reference with examples.

Comment: If the sockets are in blocking mode and you execute either `send()` or `recv()` in a loop, or in any way that isn't dictated by what `select()` just indicated, they can block. Specifically, looping until `recv()` returns zero will block until the peer closes the connection. It is customary to use non-blocking mode in conjunction with `select()`.

Comment: Even the FIRST read or recv on a socket which was returned by poll or select as "ready for reading" may block if the socket is not in non-blocking mode, as already mentioned in the BUGS section of Linux select(2) manpage (but it's no bug, actually). As to the select() followed by a reading  loop until eof, this thing certainly has its origin in some "tutorial" -- I find it unlikely that so many people go into that hole without leading each other ;-)

Comment: There's another unmentioned possible reason: if you use select with a timeout you have to make sure that it wasn't the timeout the rrason why it returned.